# Pass parameterized function and list of parameters using c++20 Concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a function `foo` that take one parameter of any type like this:

```
void foo(int& x)
{
    x = 4;
}
```

Now i want to create a templated function `bar` that takes a function with 1 parameter and a list of parameters to call the function with.

```
template<typename Func, typename Params>
void bar(Func func, Params params)
{
     for(auto param : params)
     {
         func(param);
     }
}
```

This works and compiles, but I want to improve this to use C++20 concepts. First I created an `iterable` concept like this:

```
template<typename Container, typename ElementType>
concept iterable = std::ranges::range<Container> && std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<Container>::value_type, ElementType>;
```

and used it to check if the `value_type` of the iterator is the same as the parameter type of the provided container like this:

```
template<typename Func, typename ParamType, typename Params>
requires std::invocable<Func, ParamType> && iterable<Params, ParamType>
void bar(Func func, Params params)
{
     for(auto param : params)
     {
         func(param);
     }
}
```

But this doesn't compile for this simple example

```
std::vector<int> payload(10, 5);
bar(&foo, payload);
```

with the following error message

```
error C2672: 'bar': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'void bar(Func,Params)': could not deduce template argument for 'ParamType'
```

Which somewhat makes sense as Func and Params are arguments of the function and ParamType is not, but I want to solve this without having to manually specify the type of parameter. I also tried changing the signature to `void bar(Func func, Params<ParamType> params)` or change to template to `... typename ParamType, typename Params<ParamType>>` both of which didn't compile.

How can I solve this without explicitly specifying the parameter type to bar?

Comment: "*First I created an iterable concept like this:*" Just use `range`.

Comment: I didn't look into ranges yet, but TIL that the `range` concept is exactly what `iterable` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve this by using the tools the standard library gives you. You use the`input_range` and the `invocable` concepts, providing the `range_reference_t` type of the given range as the parameter to the invoked function.

```
template<typename Func, std::ranges::input_range Rng>
  requires std::invocable<Func, std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng>>
void bar(Func func, Rng params)
{
     for(auto &&param : params)
     {
         std::invoke(func, param);
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `std::invocable<....>` or `std::is_invocable<...>::value`, but thanks, thats exactly what I need, now I have to look into ranges, they seem really useful